# Could not find a declaration file for module while importing a node module using ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, loopback

I have setup loopback 4 and trying to write a new controller for my Braintree API payments. I have installed the Braintree npm module and using

```
import {braintree} from 'braintree';
```

to import into a controller and use in an endpoint. But it is throwing me following error:

```
*src/controllers/braintree.controller.ts:23:25 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'braintree'. '/home/oem/Learning/learn-loopback/my-todo-app/node_modules/braintree/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/braintree` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'braintree';*`
```

When I try the es5 way of importing it is working fine.

Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Have you installed the `@types/braintree` declaration?

Answer (score 1):

The braintree type does not seem to exist yet. So here you have 2 possibilities:

- You create a type file as suggested in the error, but you need to have a good knowledge of the braintree library.
- Replace `import {braintree} from 'braintree';` with `const braintree = require('braintree');` but you won't have access to all the typescript magic, so be careful when manipulating this library.

Comment: and, if you choose the `require` to install and import @types/node in tsconfig.js